# Show SQL result in separate columns

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, oracle12c

I want to show this table where trading_area and reporting_unit are shown in separate columns for each id_num and name_item.

| id_num | name_item | trading_area | reporting_unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | YC | Washington | BOA |
| 1002 | NO | Utah | BCG |
| 1001 | GO | Arizona | NYP |

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT item.id_number, item.name_item, inf.info_value   
FROM traded_item item, item_info inf, item_info_types typ
WHERE item.id_number = inf.item_id
AND inf.info_type_id = typ.type_id
AND typ.type_id IN (20005, 20001) ---trading_area, reporting_unit 
ORDER BY name
```

However, this shows me the following table:

| id_num | name_item | info_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | YC | Washington |
| 1002 | NO | Utah |
| 1001 | GO | Arizona |
| 1001 | YC | BOA |
| 1002 | NO | BCG |
| 1001 | GO | NYP |

[image: Table schema]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should make `JOIN` operations explicit, using the `JOIN` keyword and the `ON` clause that specifies the matching conditions.

Then you can use two `CASE` expressions to extract your values, and the `MAX` aggregation function to remove your NULL values.

```
SELECT item.id_number, 
       item.name_item, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN typ.type_id = 20005 THEN inf.info_value END) AS trading_area,
       MAX(CASE WHEN typ.type_id = 20001 THEN inf.info_value END) AS reporting_unit 
FROM       traded_item     item
INNER JOIN item_info       inf
        ON item.id_number = inf.item_id
INNER JOIN item_info_types typ
        ON inf.info_type_id = typ.type_id
       AND typ.type_id IN (20005, 20001)
GROUP BY item.id_number, 
         item.name_item
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks again for this answer! That's exactly what I needed:-) Regarding the MAX function, I still see some blank rows for trading_area and reporting_unit. That's OK, as some of them won't have any selection, but I still want to show them.  Both of these columns are showing strings. Do you mean the MAX function would remove any entries if they were of the datatype integer?

Comment: Can you share your input table in the post? @Skywalker

Comment: If you want to show also rows that don't have any between those two "*type_id*" values, you can remove the `AND typ.type_id IN (20005, 20001)` condition from the `ON` clause.

Comment: I just added the table schema for one of the tables holding the trading_area

Comment: I'm sorry man, that doesn't help me understand how your current output differs from your expected output. Have you tried my last suggestion?